# Comparing lists in Haskell, or more specifically what is lexicographical order?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm just beginning this nice hashkell beginners tutorial:

http://learnyouahaskell.com

[on this page on lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists) he explains that lists are compared in compared in lexicographical order, he gives this example:

```
ghci> [3,2,1] > [2,10,100]
True
```

From some googling it seems to me that  lexicographical ordering means in alphabetical or sequential number ordering(?), but I still can't make sense of this evaluating to True.

I'm missing something obvious here, can anybody help?

Comment: I prefered rkhayov's answer, but, remember that with newtype you can redefine the instance of ord of any type as you wish. For example, you can redefine the ord of a list as the sum of its elements. I think that that was your first idea of "which list is greater".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This evaluates to `True` as 3 is greater than 2. Having found a result, the comparison stops here. He's demonstrating that 2 and 10 are not compared. The result of the array comparison is `true`. If the first array started with 2 as well, the comparison would result in `false`.

A nice example for when lexicographical ordering does not result in what the user would expect is file names in Windows. If you have files named `xyz1.txt`, `xyz2.txt`, `xyz10.txt` and `xyz20.txt`, the lexicographical order would be: `xyz1.txt`, `xyz10.txt`, `xyz2.txt`,  `xyz20.txt`

Comment: I don't understand... I see how your answer applies to the example above ([3,2,1] > [2,10,100]), but by your reasoning, [3,4]==[3,5] should evaluate to True because the first elements are equal.  This is not the case.

Comment: No, my reasoning is that the aim is to detect whether array x is greater or less than array y. As long as the arrays start with the same elements, this decision can not be made and thus the comparison continues. So by my reasoning [3,4] != [3,5], because 4 != 5.

Comment: Ooh, this now makes sense. Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: so what is the usage of this thing? If it stops at the first evaluation why this is used instead of a single evaluation?

Comment: It does not stop at the **first** evaluation. It continues evaluating until a decision can be made. And a decision can be made as soon as there is an `i` so that `a[i]` and `b[i]` are not equal. Otherwise the arrays are considered equal.

Answer (score 16):

"Lexicographic order" means similar to the way words
are ordered in a dictionary: if the first element of
each list is the same, compare the second elements;
if the second elements are the same, compare the thirds;
etc. If one list runs out of elements before the other,
the shorter list is "less".

Comment: Thanks for responding, I found Thorsten Dittmar a little bit easier to understand hence I ticked him.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers: actual definition of `instance Ord` for lists [in GHC] pretty much says it all:

```
instance (Ord a) => Ord [a] where
    compare []     []     = EQ
    compare []     (_:_)  = LT
    compare (_:_)  []     = GT
    compare (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of
                                EQ    -> compare xs ys
                                other -> other
```

Answer (score 3):

Example:

What happens when walking through the following?

```
[1,2,9,2] > [1,2,10,1] -- False
```

[ 1, 2, **9**, 2]

[ 1, 2,**10**, 1]

1. compare **1 > 1**, equal? yes, continue to next comparison
2. compare **2 > 2**, equal? yes, continue to next comparison
3. compare **9 > 10**, equal? no, 9 is actually less, stop and return False

Other examples

[1,2,**9**,2] < [1,2,**10**,1]   -- True

[1,2,3,**4**] <= [1,2,3,**5**]   -- True

[1,2,3,4] >= [1,2,3,4]   -- True

[1,2,3,4] <= [1,2,3,4]   -- True

Answer (score 1):

I think LearnYouAHaskell would benefit from writing the word `Only`.

```
First the heads are compared. *Only* if they are equal then the second elements are compared, etc.
```

So because 3 is greater than 2, the decision is complete and there is no need to check indexes 1 and 2.

`[3,2,1] > [2,10,100] == [3] > [2]`

It can also be thought of a bit like a sortable date

`2019-07-06 > 2011-08-09`

If you do that in your head, you checked the years first, and don't need to check the months or days now to know the the first date is greater.

Answer (score 0):

Just understand this: comparing two lists doesn't mean comparing the values of all the elements in each list. Rather it means simply comparing the lexical order of each element in list1 with the corresponding element in list2, and returning the result as soon as it found that the two elements are ordered differently lexically.