# Applying isAlpha to a recursive function

Tags: haskell

I've created the function `filter` that finds the smallest item in a list and filters out any strings that contain characters that are not alphabetical. For example

```
filter ["a","bb","ccc","dddd","e","f"] = "a"
```

But isAlpha doesn't seem to be working if I use this example I get `filter ["**", "a", "?"] = "**"` instead of `= "a"`

```
filter :: [String] -> String
filter [] = error "String is Empty"
filter [x] = x  
filter (x:y:xs) = if x < y && all isAlpha x then g(x:xs) else g(y:xs)
```

Comment: Don't name your function `filter`, as it is *not* a filter (though it can be implemented *using* `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` defined in the `base` library).

Comment: @CamelBak: please first *specify* the function. How do you compare strings here? Why is `"a"` smaller than `"?"`?

Comment: Sorry. As "?" is not alphabetical.

Comment: Comparing strings using `<` does not really involve string lengths. Strings are ordered *lexicographically*, just like the words in a dictionary. Character '*'  appears before 'a' in the Unicode and ASCII sequences. Hence both expressions `("*" < "a")` and `("*xyz" < "a")` evaluate to True. More details in  [SO-q3651144](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651144/comparing-lists-in-haskell-or-more-specifically-what-is-lexicographical-order).

Comment: @CamelBak: so for a list of non-alphabetical strings `["**", "?"]`, what is the expected result?

Comment: an empty string

Comment: Why would `["**", "?"]` return an empty string, but `[]` raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid we'll need to pick another name for your function, say “smallest”, as we are going to need the library version of `filter`:  [`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter).

The regular `minimum` function, when applied to character strings, returns a lexicographically minimal value, definitely not what we want  here.

However, many library functions, such as `group`, `sort`, `minimum`, have a sibling whose name ends with “By”. When the simpler function cannot do the intended task, one can eventually use the sibling function instead. The sibling takes an extra functional argument which allows the caller to customize the task at hand somehow.

For example, you have a `minimumBy` function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type minimumBy
 minimumBy :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> t a -> a
 λ>
```

The first naïve idea is to try `minimumBy length`, but that would not even typecheck: function `length` returns an `Int`, not an `Ordering` value, which can be `GT` or `LT` or `EQ`.

So we need some plumbing function between `minimumBy` and `length`. The type signature of the plumbing function would have to be something like `Ord c => (a -> c) -> (a -> a -> Ordering)`, with `a` being the String type and `c` the `Int` type.

Before writing such a function from scratch, we can check whether or not it has been included in the library. We check this by submitting the required type signature into [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org).

[Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) immediately [points us](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Ord%20c%3D%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20Ordering)) to function [`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing).

That function does the job:

```
 λ>
 λ> import  Data.Ord
 λ>
 λ> :type comparing
 comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
 λ> 
 λ> :type  minimumBy (comparing length)
 minimumBy (comparing length)
  :: (Foldable t1, Foldable t2) => t1 (t2 a) -> t2 a
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> minimum ["aaa","bb","cccx","eer"]
 "aaa"
 λ> 
 λ> minimumBy (comparing length) ["aaa","bb","cccx","eer"]
 "bb"
 λ>
```

A preliminary task consists in eliminating those strings which contain non-alphabetical characters. This can be done as described in the excellent answer by Kevin P. Barry, and involves the `filter` *library function*.

**In summary:**

```
import  Data.List  (minimumBy)
import  Data.Ord   (comparing)
import  Data.Char  (isAlpha)

smallest :: [String] -> String
smallest sts = let  alphas = filter  (all isAlpha)  sts
               in   if (null alphas)
                        then  error "No alphabetic strings in list"
                        else  minimumBy (comparing length) alphas
```

Testing under `ghci`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> smallest ["aaa","bb","cccx","dddd-","eer","+"] 
"bb"
 λ>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare by lengths, not the strings themselves, so you're looking for `if length x <= length y` as opposed to `if x < y`. The `<=` ensures that the first occurrence in a tie is used instead of the last.

Comment: Thanks, But how would I check if the string contains all letters ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` from `Prelude`, can you just use `head . sort . filter (all isAlpha)`? Or, if you want to preserve your current error message, `head . (++["String is Empty"]) . sort . filter (all isAlpha)`.

The key here is to use the *functional* characteristics of Haskell to your advantage, rather than hand-writing something recursive. If you know how a single-purpose function behaves (e.g., `all`, `filter`, `sort`) then you can just construct your function by composing those known behaviors.

Since most Haskell functions are lazy, only the computations necessary to compute the final result will be executed. So, if only some of the elements need to be sorted to find the smallest, then the other operations will be skipped at runtime.

You can *incrementally* build your function in this way, also. For example, start with `filter (all isAlpha)`, then do `sort . filter (all isAlpha)`, etc. to see what the intermediate data is during prototyping.

---

Side note: It's generally better to use something like `Either` or `Maybe` to deal with errors so that they can't accidentally be ignored. So, `head . (++[Nothing]) . map Just . sort . filter (all isAlpha)` would give you `Nothing` if none of the strings are alpha, and `Just "a"` (etc.) for success.

Comment: You *can* use `sort` that way, taking advantage of the specific characteristics of the implementation of `sort` in `base`. But it's much clearer, and probably significantly faster, to use `minimum`.

Comment: @dfeuer Sometimes a concise solution that demonstrates a point is preferable to one that's efficient but messier. The point being demonstrated is that you can often solve a problem by composing other functions; the solution isn't meant for production. `minimum []` = ⊥ and `minimum (xs ++ [Nothing])` = `Nothing`, both of which complicate specifying the behavior when the list is empty after filtering. Using `minimum` probably requires some sort of branching, such as pattern matching, `if`/`then`/`else`, `|`, etc., which would obscure the point.